# Modifying monad state

Tags: haskell, tree, state, monads

For a programming exercise, I am supposed to take a Tree of data type

```
data Tree a = Branch (Tree a) a (Tree a) | Leaf
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

and label each `a` with an `Int`, increasingly, depth-first in-order, using a state monad, and count the number of monadic actions. For example, the expression

```
let tree = Branch (Branch Leaf "B" Leaf) "A" Leaf
in run (label tree) 42
```

should evaluate to

```
(Branch (Branch Leaf (42, "B") Leaf) (43, "A") Leaf
, Counts {binds = 10,returns = 5, gets = 4, puts = 2})
```

The type of the state is:

```
newtype State' s a = State' { runState' :: (s, Counts) -> (a, s, Counts) }
```

Here are my implementations of `label` and `run`

```
label :: MonadState m Int => Tree a -> m (Tree (Int, a))
label Leaf                      = return Leaf
label (Branch left value right) = do
                                  newLeft  <- label left
                                  int <- get
                                  put (int + 1)
                                  newRight <- label right
                                  return (Branch newLeft (int, value) newRight)


run :: State' s a -> s -> (a, Counts)
run s ns = let (a, _, counts) = runState' s (ns, Counts 0 0 0 0) in (a, counts)
```

However, when I run the test case, my result is

```
(Branch (Branch Leaf (42,"B") Leaf) (42,"A") Leaf
, Counts {binds = 12, returns = 5, gets = 6, puts = 2})
```

It seems the `Int` isn't being updated at all. This is strange because there are seperate test cases for each part of the assignment, and everything except this is correct. In any case, here are the get and put implementations:

```
-- get :: State' s s
get = State' (\(s, counts) -> (s, s, counts <> oneGet))

-- put :: s -> State' s ()
put x = State' (\(x, counts) -> ((), x, counts <> onePut))
```

I am really at a loss here. I have no idea why the `Int`s are not affected at all. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Although you haven't shown the implementation of `instance Monad State'` I can almost guarantee it doesn't satisfy the monad laws; counting `return`s and `bind`s is incompatible with the laws `return x >>= f = f x` and `m >>= return = m`. (Not that it's related to your problem at all!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in

```
put x = State' (\(x, counts) -> ((), x, counts <> onePut))
```

Here you're supposed to put `x` into a state, but it gets shadowed in the `(x, counts)` pattern. Make it

```
put x = State' (\(_, counts) -> ((), x, counts <> onePut))
```

and you should be fine as long as you don't care about monad laws, because your task forces you to violate them:

> count the number of monadic actions

One of the laws is `(return x >>= f) ~ f x`, but the former expression has additional `return` and `(>>=)` in it.

Comment: @D.Ondor Turning on warnings using `-Wall` would have spotted the double binding of `x`. Many pitfalls are similarly detected by warnings, so it's generally recommended to turn them on.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an assignment, but I want to point out that GHC can write almost all of this code for you! The magic words are `deriving Traversable`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, DeriveFoldable, DeriveTraversable #-}
data Tree a = Leaf
            | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)
            deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable)
```

The `Traversable` class abstracts the notion of performing an action on each element of a structure. `traverse :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)` takes a function which performs an `Applicative` effect on elements `a` and runs it over the whole structure `t`, sequencing the effects to produce a `t` in an `Applicative` context.

So all we have to do is say how to act on a single element,

```
inc :: a -> State Int (Int, a)
inc x = do
    counter <- get
    put (counter + 1)
    return (counter, x)
```

and the `Traversable` machinery will do the heavy lifting of running the action across the whole tree.

```
label :: Tree a -> Tree (Int, a)
label t = evalState (traverse inc t) 0
```

The layout of the `Node` constructor determines the traversal order; in this case `traverse` will perform an in-order traversal.